# How can i prevent a process (script) from suspending (freezing) in android?

Tags: android, bash, sleep, freeze, suspend

I have a script which run a command after wait for some minute

```
#!/sbin/busybox sh
while true; do
sleep 3600;
sync;
sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=2;
done;
```

but this script will pause after some second as soon as android device goes to sleep.
Each time the device wake up the script continue counting.
How can i make this script that never suspend (freeze)? I also set -1000 to "oom_score_adj" to not kill by oom.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

How do I prevent an Android device from going to sleep programmatically?
From the root shell (e.g. adb shell), you can lock with:

```
echo mylockname >/sys/power/wake_lock
```

After which the device will stay awake, until you do:

```
echo mylockname >/sys/power/wake_unlock
```

With the same string for 'mylockname'.

Note that this will not prevent the screen from going black, but it will prevent the CPU from sleeping.

Note that `/sys/power/wake_lock` is `read-write` for `user` radio (1001) and `group` system (1000), and, of course, root.

So I guess your script would be:

```
#!/sbin/busybox sh
echo mylockname >/sys/power/wake_lock;
while true; do
sleep 3600;
sync;
sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=2;
done;
echo mylockname >/sys/power/wake_unlock;
```

[reference](http://lwn.net/Articles/479841/)
[reference 1](http://elinux.org/Android_Power_Management)

Comment: awsome,thanks..so i just need to send my script name "script" or script.sh" to the sysfs.right ?! what else if there is the same name process ? can i do this with PID ?

Comment: 'mylockname' is just a string, any string. put the code in your script, and it will run. I added another link.

Comment: God bless you man, you lead me to the right way. seems wakelock for keeping process active look at the source which send the string to wake_lock sysfs, os it can be anything the important part is which process or anything sent that to the wake_lock sysfs.if i found anything else i'll update here else this is correct. Huge thanks man